# Inflate multiple layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

Inside a fragment I try to inflate two layouts besides the root layout:

```
View a, b;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

    //..
    a = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_list_view, container);
    b = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_list_view, container);
    //..

    return root;
}

public void showB() {
    a.setVisibility(GONE);
    b.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}
```

So I just return a single layout from the onCreateView method. However I inflate two more, a and b.

However when I display **b** actually **a** will be displayed. So progress_list_view never shows up. Can someone explain this strange behavior?

I suspect that a and b are both added to the container (ViewGroup). And since a is added first, it will be displayed first.

Comment: Why don't you inflate new view in the same container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**edit:**

The point is, you're doing a huge mess and there is no good reason why you're doing it.

What happens there is that you inflate root, but not attach it to the container with this line `View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);`

Then you inflate two views and add them directly to the container with those lines `a = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_list_view, container);`, which is a wrong thing to do as per Fragment documentation:

> The fragment should not add the view itself, but this can be used to generate the LayoutParams of the view

also both `a` and `b` are the same object, which is the `container` object as per documentation for the `LayoutInflater`

> If root was supplied, this is the root

and root was supplied by you and it's the `container`, so what you have is basically the same as`a=container;` `b=container;`

and then you return root, at which point I really don't know what is happening anymore due to this mess. I decribed.

**Lucky to fix is easy:**

create another XML layout like this (shortened):

```
<FrameLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/empty_list_view"/>
    <include layout="@layout/progress_list_view"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

then you inflate this new XML:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_xml, container, false);
    a = root.findViewById( .. ID of the root of empty_list_view.. )
    b = root.findViewById( .. ID of the root of progress_list_view.. )
    return root;
}
```

then the code will work.

**original answer:**

There's no strange behavior. You inflated those layouts and you have 2 `View` objects that are representative of them. But nothing attached those `Views` to the UI.

Only the view that you return from the `onCreateView` method that will be attached to the device UI.

For example:

the following code will show `a`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //..
    View a = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_list_view, container);
    View b = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_list_view, container);
    //..
    return a;
}
```

the following code will show `b`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //..
    View a = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_list_view, container);
    View b = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_list_view, container);
    //..
    return b;
}
```

if you want to have them both togeher you should put them together in the XML layout file. Maybe using an `include` tag if you need it re-usable.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear about my specific problem. I edited my question.

Comment: see edited answer. Long story short, you're doing a big mess on your code, but it's easy to fix.

Comment: I did not include the reason why I need this because it is not in the scope of this question. But you helped me do understand the container problem. So +1 ✅

Answer (score 1):

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout layoutMain = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    setContentView(layoutMain);
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)       getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // 1st Layout
    RelativeLayout layoutLeft = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
        R.layout.main, null);

    // 2nd Layout
    RelativeLayout layoutRight = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(
       R.layout.row, null);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutMain.addView(layoutLeft, 100, 100);
    layoutMain.addView(layoutRight, relParam);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one view from the onCreateView. The view that is returned is the view that is displayed. Looks like you always return view a.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear about my specific problem. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

R.layout.list_fragment should look something like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <include 
        android:id="@+id/a"
        layout="@layout/empty_list_view"/>
    <include 
        android:id="@+id/b"
        layout="@layout/progress_list_view"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Your code will look something like this:

```
View a, b;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    a = root.findViewById(R.id.a);
    b = root.findViewById(R.id.b);

    return root;
}

public void showB() {
    a.setVisibility(GONE);
    b.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you inflate new view in the container.

Try this

```
LayoutInflater mInflater  = null;  
ViewGroup mContainer = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mInflater = inflater;
    mContainer = container;
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    return root;
}

public void showB() {
    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_list_view, mContainer, false);
}


public void showA() {
    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_list_view, mContainer, false);
}
```