# Two layouts in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am an amateur in Android. Is it possible to add second layout in Fragment?
For example :

```
View1 view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b, container, false);

public class c extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It has no sense... yo have to do two different fragments. Anyway, why do you want this?

Comment: The answer is already there on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247542/inflate-multiple-layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create one xml and ad to your view and inflate it like this

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
```

Then goes to your main.xml and include your two layouts using

```
 < include >layout-1 < /include >

 < include >layout-2 < /include >
```

or you can dynamically inflate this 2 layouts and add to your main view

Comment: Thanks Jithu P.S :)

Comment: let me know is it works for you or not.if its work please accept the answer.