# How to use two different layout in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

I have a fragment called 'CategoriesFragment' which contains a list view. I want to show the products in a grid view when I click items in the listView. Here is my onCreateView method in the CategoriesFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);
    final String[] names={"IT","Fashion","Furniture","Garden","Toys","Sport","Cosmetics","Supermarket","Book"};
    final Product[] it={new Product("Asus Vivobook 15.6","5000TL",R.drawable.pc1),new Product("Asus Vivobook 15.6","5000TL",R.drawable.pc1),new Product("Asus Vivobook 15.6","5000TL",R.drawable.pc1),new Product("Asus Vivobook 15.6","5000TL",R.drawable.pc1),
            new Product("Asus Vivobook 15.6","5000TL",R.drawable.pc1),new Product("Asus Vivobook 15.6","5000TL",R.drawable.pc1),new Product("Asus Vivobook 15.6","5000TL",R.drawable.pc1),new Product("Asus Vivobook 15.6","5000TL",R.drawable.pc1)};
    int [] images={R.drawable.pc1,R.drawable.box,R.drawable.bell,R.drawable.info,R.drawable.creditcard,R.drawable.logout,R.drawable.creditcard,R.drawable.logout,R.drawable.logout};
    AccountAdapter accountAdapter=new AccountAdapter(getContext(),names,images);
    

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_listView);
    final View view1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.product, container, false);


    listView.setAdapter(accountAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            if(names[position].equals("IT")){

                gridView =(GridView) view1.findViewById(R.id.products);
                ProductAdapter productAdapter=new ProductAdapter(getContext(),it);
                gridView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
            }


        }
    });
```

When I execute the app, ı get the error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one view can be inflated, if you try to inflate the other it actually returns the rootview only.

What you can do is, create a single view and inflate both the layouts in that view itself and hide and show visibility on your condition.

```
<LinearLayout>
<include layout="@layout/fragment_categories"/>
<include layout="@layout/product"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and just infalte this xml as your rootview and check it.
A detail explanation is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32247688/9294340)